# Verification of flash video using selenium webdriver(java)

Tags: java, flash, selenium, webdriver

Can we verify the flash video pixels, total video run time using selenium Webdriver?

I have a website which displays same video in different pixels according to the browser/mobile device. I want to know the pixel size used in a specific device through selenium. is it possible?

I have already tried RC jar for flash verification i.e. FlashSelenium. But as much as I can understand it's just for the verification using standard methods and functions to start and stop the videos. I also had gone through different websites, but there was no useful answer I have found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that certain pixels have a specific color in the video? I think this can be a very complicated task. The actual colors may depend on the video stream decoder and the system clock, stream jitter and other things.

Comment: No, its not related to any colors. i have a website which displays same video in different pixels according to the browser/mobile device. I want to know the pixel size used in a specific device through selenium. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Flash objects are not exposed at client side.  This is not part of DOM, so you can not verify directly using selenium webdriver. 
You can ask dev team to write some js function in your application which communicate with flash objects and return pixel size. In this way you can get pixel size by invoking js function using selenium.

Comment: Thanks Sadik, will try same with dev team.